# In Lion can I get the four fingere swipe to do COMMAND+Tab?

Tags: macos, trackpad

I recently switched to Lion from Snow Leopard (Yah I know, I am late), it is great, the only one thing that I miss is the four fingere swipe that did COMMAND+TAB

Is there anyway I can enable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## BetterTouchTool

can surely do this and a lot more! Enjoy:

http://www.boastr.de/

[image]

Comment: If on Lion, make sure to read http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=2507 other wise it would be hard to get it to work properly, great tool it is though.