# How can I make rows and columns for Spaces in Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces

I just recently switched to Lion from Snow leopard and dealing with a few issues (like [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32709/in-lion-can-i-get-the-four-fingere-swipe-to-do-commandtab))

I am still loving it, though.

I used to have 3 X 3 spaces (I know, it's insane for some, but I like it), and liked that I can arrange things in a spatial arrangement.
Now on Lion I get a 1 X 9 series of spaces, is there a way to enable the column X row configuration of Spaces in Snow Leopard back?

EDIT: I've been using the four-fingere-up gesture for a while now and I dont miss spaces as much anymore!

Comment: This frustrated me too, because I also had 9 spaces, arranged in a 3x3 grid. I still have my 10.6 iMac that way, and getting used to the new version has taken some time. Actually, I still get lost sometimes, a problem I never used to have...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mission Control desktop spaces are strictly linear. 1x9 is all you have, and 1x9 is all you'll get (for the foreseeable future anyways).

Given the use of 9(!) desktop spaces, the two fastest ways to navigate explicitly to one of them are the keyboard shortcuts, or explicitly launching the Mission Control interface and clicking on the specific desktop space you wish to use.

After creating multiple spaces, you can go into your System Preferences and define a keyboard shortcut for each specific space.

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts tab -> Mission Control category
[image: System Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts menu]

Answer (score 8):

I’m pretty certain that you can't; you just get a single-line.

From [John Siracusa’s review of Lion](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7.ars/6) (when describing the implementation of spaces in Mission Control):

> The biggest limitation of this new arrangement is that Spaces are now confined to a one-dimensional line of virtual desktops. Four-finger swiping between spaces feels great, but there's no wrap-around when you hit the end.

Answer (score 4):

A new utility call ReSpaceApp promises this functionality:

http://www.macworld.com/article/1166316/promising_prospect_respaceapp_brings_spaces_to_lion.html

Comment: ReSpaceApp is now [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/), and the [release history](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/changes) shows that they have been releasing updates frequently